# Why does PDO returns two array keys?

Tags: php, pdo

I am using a simple `SELECT` in `PDO`:

```
$status = 'subscribed';
$statement = $pdo->prepare("select id_user from user where status = :status");
$statement->bindParam(':status', $status);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch();
print_r($row);
```

Why does it return:

```
Array ( [id_user] => 9 [0] => 9 )
```

Instead of:

```
Array ( [id_user] => 9 )
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, just some *solid advice* in saying that it's *good practice* to use uppercase for words such as **SELECT** and **FROM** and **WHERE** etc. It just makes it soOoo much easier to read and set it apart from queries. *You'll probably end up thanking me for it later on* ;-)

Comment: ^ That is totally a personal style preference. If you write for a company or for an established project, just follow the existing conventions. Personally, I write in all lowercase.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I agree on those points. It just makes it easier for "me" to differentiate from a potentially long line of code at times, and from what I've seen/gathered on the MySQL Website, they have theirs all in uppercase. So yes, it's a matter of personal taste/writing form. *"Just my 2 cents"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because PDO defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, if you only want the fieldname as key, use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

```php
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or change the default fetch mode to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
// for the PDO instance (which all pdostatement instances will inherit)
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// for the PDOStatement instance
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify
    `$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 0):

See the options for PDO fetch:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

It defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` rather than `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Answer (score 0):

Default value for `PDOStatement::fetch` is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. It means you can access the data by 'name' and 'index'.
If you only want the associative version use this:

```
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```